# Sub-domain in Internal DNS reference to External Vendor site

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, subdomain, dynamic-ip

Suppose we own the domain (***example.com***) & setup it into our External & Internal DNS server.  And, we have a website created by our vendor using our sub-domain name (***vendor.example.com***).  The vendor has setup the Name Server (***ns1.vendor.com***) to return the IP-address dynamically based on their Global Load Balancer.

Now,

- In our External DNS server, we already setup a sub-domain pointing to the vendor Name Server (***ns1.vendor.com***).

  ```
  vendor    IN    NS    ns1.vendor.com
  ```

  And, it works for Internet users.
- In our Internal DNS server, we need to setup the same sub-domain for internal staffs.  But, the Internal DNS server cannot query the vendor name server (*ns1.vendor.com*) for the IP-address.

  We tried to setup the same NS record in our Internal DNS server.  However, it failed because the DNS server cannot access to Internet.

Questions:

1. What should we do to make it work for Internal staffs querying through our Internal DNS server?
2. Does it work if we replace the NS record in our Internal DNS pointing to our External Name Server (***ns1.example.com***) as in the following example?

   ```
   vendor    IN    NS    ns1.example.com
   ```

Comment: Sounds like a case for conditional forwarders.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Could you show the details on what we should set for the conditional forwarders?  Thanks!